# Instagram Api with MongoDB and PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, real-time, instagram

I am have been wrestling with the realtime instagram api for a class project. I have a subscription and callback script that pushes the data into mongoDB. Everything works great and I receive updates, but the $data array is empty on all of them. I can't seem to find why I'm not receiving data back with the updates. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code and I attached a screenshot of my mongoDB result.

***Subscribe script

```
<?php
//Subscribe

//ALL YOUR IMPORTANT API INFO
$client_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$object = 'geography';
$lat = '39.73';
$lng = '-104.98';
$radius = '5000';
$aspect = 'media';
$verify_token='';
$callback_url = 'http://www.callback.com';


//SETTING UP THE CURL SETTINGS

$attachment =  array(
'client_id' => $client_id,
'client_secret' => $client_secret,
'object' => $object,
'lat' => $lat,
'lng' => $lng,
'radius' => $radius,
'aspect' => $aspect,
'verify_token' => $verify_token,
'callback_url'=>$callback_url
);

//URL TO THE INSTAGRAM API FUNCTION
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/";

$ch = curl_init();

//EXECUTE THE CURL...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  //to suppress the curl output 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

//PRINT THE RESULTS OF THE SUBSCRIPTION, IF ALL GOES WELL YOULL SEE A 200
print_r($result);


?>
```

****Callback script

```
<?php

//Callback

if (isset ($_GET['hub_challenge'])){
    echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
}

else {
    //database config
    $dbhost = '@myserver';
    $dbname = 'test';

    //connect to database
    $m = new Mongo("mongodb://$dbhost");
    $db = $m->$dbname;

    //select the collection
    $collection = $db->instagram;

    //This is an update
    $myString = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $ALL = date("F j, Y, g:i a")." ".$myString."\r\n";
    file_put_contents('activity1.log', $ALL, FILE_APPEND);
    $answer = json_decode($myString);
    $collection->save($answer);
}
?>
```

When I open RoboMongo I get the keys I recieve are object id, changed aspect, object, time, subscription id. Then there is a data array that is always empty. I can't figure how to the info from this.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem. Data is always empty.

Comment: Could you post the entries in activity1.log? Is the data field filled out there? If so, then you are using the instagram api incorrectly (I haven't used that api so I don't know which arguments it takes, or your callback script should take...)